# Saving one proportion of a list in one varaible and the other in another using iter()

Tags: python, list, iterator

I am attempting to split a list into 2 lists, divided into uneven splits. I have this working by applying the iter() function as seen in the final line:

```
def crossover():
    end = len(bestPop) - 1

    for i in range(0, end, 2):
        crossPoint = (random.randint(1, len(range(stringLen - 2))))
        crossPoint2 = stringLen - crossPoint

        listA = pop[bestPop[i]]
        listB = pop[bestPop[end - i]]

        sizes = [crossPoint, crossPoint2]
        it = iter(listA)
        print([[next(it) for _ in range(size)] for size in sizes])
```

This creates a random porportion to the sum of 20 (eg. 17 and 3 & 6 and 14) in order to split the list. This works succesfully and prints out:

> [['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1'], ['1', '1', '1']]

However I was wondering how I would go about saving list one to one list variable and list two to another.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What if you do this: lists=[[next(it) for _ in range(size)] for size in sizes] variable1= lists[0] variable2=lists[1]

Comment: I tried this initialiy and i got this error  

"File "main.py", line 66, in <listcomp>
    lists = [[next(itA) for _ in range(size)] for size in sizes]
StopIteration"

Comment: Would you share the whole code if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, but unfortunatley , not with an iterator. This is my solution

```
def crossover():
    end = len(bestPop) - 1
    print("sdaasd" + str(bestPop))
    for i in range(0, end, 2):
        crossPoint = (random.randint(1, len(range(stringLen - 2))))
        crossPoint2 = stringLen - crossPoint

        listA = pop[bestPop[i]]
        listB = pop[bestPop[end - i]]

        sizes = [crossPoint, crossPoint2]
        parA1, parA2 = splitList(sizes, listA)
        parB1, parB2 = splitList(sizes, listB)

        childA = list(chain(parA1, parB2))
        childB = list(chain(parB1, parA2))
        pop.append(childA)
        pop.append(childB)
    


def splitList(sizes, list):
    par1 = []
    par2 = []

    for s in range(-division):
        if s < sizes[0]:
            par1.append(list[s])
        else:
            par2.append(list[s])

    return par1, par2
```

This outputs:

> PARENT B = ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
> '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0']

> List a of size -15['0','1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0']
>
> List b of size -5['1', '1', '0', '1', '0']